# Get the json values in Http.get

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-services

I was trying to create a small example in Angular2. What I am doing is when I click a button, this does a get to public api and show a quotes, but I can't, the value never shows and I got the error

> Cannot read property 'quotes' of undefined in
>   [{{quote.contents.quotes.quote}} in App@4:20]

My Component.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit, Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http, HTTP_PROVIDERS, URLSearchParams} from 'angular2/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: `<ul>
                <li (click)='myAlert()'> Helow World</li>
             </ul>
             <div>
              <spam>{{quote.contents.quotes.quote}}</spam>
             </div>`,
  providers: [HTTP_PROVIDERS]
})

export class App {
  public quote: Object;
  public  logError: string;

  constructor(private http: Http){
    this.quote = {};
  }

  myAlert(){
      this.http.get("http://quotes.rest/qod.json").map(res => { return res.json()})
        .subscribe(
          data => this.quote = data,
          err => this.logError(err),
          () => console.log('Random Quote Complete')
      );

  }
}
```

My boot.ts

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser'
import {App} from './component'
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';

bootstrap(App, [HTTP_PROVIDERS]).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Index.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>


    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.1/http.js"></script>

    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script>
    System.config({
      packages: {
        app: {
          format: 'register',
          defaultExtension: 'js'
        }
      }
    });
      System.import('app/boot')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>

  </head>

  <!-- 3. Display the application -->
  <body>
    <app>Loading...</app>
  </body>

</html>
```

How Do I get the values from the service's subscribe and put into my template?

Comment: it's probably because of the http call be asynchronous. Angular will evaluate your template and the 1st time it happens it the quote property will be null. Try using the async pipe. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/AsyncPipe-class.html

Comment: also, until the http call is actually done the quote field will just be an empty object. When angular evaluates {{quote.contents.quotes.quote}} it will end up with that error. because there's no 'contents' property on that object.

Comment: @toskv thanks a lot for your help, let me try you suggest and I back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the template is loaded `quote.contents` is undefined. Also I noticed that `quote.contents` contains and Array.  after that I changed `myAlert()` method to:

```
myAlert(){
      this.http.get("http://quotes.rest/qod.json").map(res => { return res.json()})
        .subscribe(
          data => { this.quote = data.contents.quotes[0].quote; this.author = data.contents.quotes[0].author;},
          err => this.logError(err),
          () => console.log('Random Quote Complete')
      );
  }
```

And the component to:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: `<ul>
                <li (click)='myAlert()'> Helow World</li>
             </ul>
             <div>
              <spam>{{quote}}</spam>
              <br>
              <spam>{{author}}</spam>
             </div>`,
  providers: [HTTP_PROVIDERS]
})
```

And now works.

**Note**: I don't have a lot skills with `Typescript` and `Angular2` maybe there is another way.

Comment: self answer good job !! but you don't need to provide `HTTP_PROVIDERS` as provider while you had already provide same at the time of Bootstrap. secondly yes if `{{quote.contents.quotes.quote}}` is null first time it may throws error but there is one alternate for the same you have to put `?` sign in the expression like this `{{abc?}}` that mean if abc is null it will not throw any error. hope it will help you for next time !!

Comment: @PardeepJain Thanks for the tip. But is rarely that ? or elvis operator does not work to object with array look (that)[https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6798]

Comment: seems your suggested link is expired check it again !

Comment: @PardeepJain you are welcome, I wrote this issuses yestarday, because the suggest works, without array. Thanks for your help.